# Merging functionality from two controllers; should I place all actions in one controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Say I have 2 controllers, `OrderController` and `StatusController`. `OrderController` has several CRUD actions for Orders and `StatusController` has several actions pertinent to changing the satus of Orders (from created to sent, cancelled, etc).

`StatusController` really only has one view where several actions can be performed, but for the sake of usability I've decided to merge the functionality of this one view with the Index action of `OrdersController`. (This is just an adapted example for the question, so bear with me if it sounds silly).

Only by copy/pasting the Html in the views from here to there everything works, of course, but...

What should I do with the actions on `StatusController`? Should I move them to `OrderController` or Should I let `StatusController` exist even though it has no views? I think it might be better than having `OrderController` have 15 actions, but is this desirable? Is there a recommended good practice/approach in such case?

Comment: Do the methods in the StatusController return ActionResults that use views under the OrdersController views folder?

Comment: @Mike - No, they don't. They were originally written as 2 separate sections, so no dependencies there. Besides, after the "merge", actions in StatusController are only used in Ajax calls returning Json results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment above to my question where you stated that the Status controller is only used for AJAX calls currently I would still leave it separate from the Orders controller.

The MVC idea is that the controller acts like a traffic cop for incoming requests and determining the out going responses. Even though you aren't returning a view per say you still have Status specific requests (via AJAX) and responses (via JSON) to the web server which warrants a seperation.

Perhaps to keep the naming more concise you could rename the Status controller to OrderStatusController since it sounds like it acts purely on status for the orders.